# How to create several translate animation sequentially in android?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, translate

I' m new in anroid programming and i want  to create sequential translate animations. I have ten images,   what i want is as follows:

- I choose image randomly and create translate animation for this image. Also, same image can exist more than one times on the screen and these translate animations shouldn' t wait  other animations end. In other words, more than one animations should exist on screen at the same time.

I fight with this on two days and still I could not do what I wanted. If you give an idea or a piece of codes, i will be gratefull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean sequentially or simultaneously?

Comment: Actually, i want both, sequantially and simultaneously.